# How do I animate paperjs onMouseEnter/Leave?

Tags: paperjs

All examples I see of paperjs involving movement, happens inside of onFrame, but how do I animate on mouse events?

```
var circle1 = new Shape.Circle(new Point(80, 50), 30);

circle1.strokeColor = 'green';
circle1.fillColor = 'green';

circle1.onMouseEnter = function (event) {

    circle1.scale(1.2);

}
```

This works, but it doesn't animate.

Answer (score 0):

You can make animation with setInterval like below code.

```
var circle1 = new Shape.Circle(new Point(80, 50), 30);
circle1.strokeColor = 'green';
circle1.fillColor = 'green';
circle1.onMouseEnter = function (event) {
    var totalScale = 1
    var id = setInterval(function(){
        var scale = 1.01
        totalScale *= scale;
        if(totalScale > 2){
            clearInterval(id)
        }
        circle1.scale(scale);
    } , 50)
}
```

Add: [onFrame] version, is this what you want?

```
var circle1 = new Shape.Circle(new Point(80, 50), 30);
circle1.strokeColor = 'green';
circle1.fillColor = 'green';
circle1.onMouseEnter = function (event) {
    circle1.onFrame = function(){
        circle1.scale(1.01)
    }
}
circle1.onMouseLeave = function (event) {
    circle1.onFrame = null
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that, but that defeats the purpose of having paperjs' frame animation function. I believe I can run onFrame for any item created and not just for the view. I am still trying out to see if it will work.